# How to force action in "on click" on some condition?

Tags: jquery

```
$(".button").on("click", function(){
        if (this.id == "Intro"){
            if(!$("#intro-container").hasClass('active')){
                $("#content").find(".active").removeClass('active').fadeOut(300, function(){
                    $("#intro-container").fadeIn(300).addClass('active');
                });            
            }
        }; 
});  

if ($("#container-main").hasClass('sended')){

       $("#Intro") __?action?__
   }
```

I'd like to force action like in $(".button") on click method. What to insert into `__?action?__`  ?

Comment: What action to force? Your question is not clear at all. How `$("#Intro")` is related to `$(".button")`

Comment: Do you mean that you want to do the same thing that click-event does when #container-main has class sended?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I'd like to make action like in click if condition is met.

Comment: $("#Intro")  is Id contained class  $(".button")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to trigger a click event:

```
$("#Intro").trigger("click");
```

Answer (score 0):

First move the function from the click method into a named function that you call from the on click event:

```
var makeIntroActive = function () { ... };

$(".button").on("click", makeIntroActive);
```

Then if you want to do the same thing in another context, just call the same function directly:

```
makeIntroActive();
```